# I need to know how to update the UI in the bootstrap hamburger menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, media-queries

I am having an issue finding a way to change the hamburger dropdown from slide down to slide right and use the same elements. I've seen samples where they swap out one menu for the other at breakpoints but I want to use just one menu to achieve both. I have the basic code here.

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a>

        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

I am looking everywhere for a solution for this. The reason I cannot swap menus is because the menu items will have to be updated regularly and I don't want to have to do it in two spaces.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/qw93eLy6/2/

Comment: This might be what you are looking for :) - http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Off-canvas-Push-Menu-jQuery-Plugin-For-Bootstrap.html

Comment: Hmmm. Trying to get this to work in a jsfiddle and it's not. What am I missing I wonder? https://fiddle.jshell.net/qw93eLy6/8/

Comment: You want it to slide in like this? http://www.codeply.com/go/p6JYGuVQ3y

Comment: Wow! Yes just like that except I want it to slide in from the right. How are you guys finding this. I searched for 15 hours.

Comment: I tried to get this to jsfiddle and it doesn't. It's like I'm missing some javascript. https://jsfiddle.net/galnova/o79pt9bv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check it my local Its Working fine please check it, and you should include this head file.
If you have your jquery,css file then include that file

```
 <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">Bootstrap theme <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried what you had rubin, but the slideout isn't working. https://jsfiddle.net/galnova/ha2o1xsj/ I can't use bootstrap 4 alpha so I switched it to 3.3.7. Any Idea on how to get the slideout to work?